# How to stop column from being resized by width in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to prevent column from being resized larger than 10px. I want it to be small because it contains only checkbox.

I instantiate JTable here:

```
private void initDataSearchResultTable()
    {
        dataSearchResultTable = new JTable();
        dataSearchResultTable.setSelectionBackground(new Color(0xaaaaff));
        dataSearchResultTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        dataSearchResultTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        dataSearchResultTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        dataSearchResultTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    }
```

I set Table model for table(when user clicks button) here:

```
void updateDataSearchTableModel(CachedRowSet cachedRowSet)
    {
        TableModel tableModel = dataSearchResultTable.getModel();
        if (tableModel instanceof DataSearchTableModel) {
            ((DataSearchTableModel) tableModel).updateModel(cachedRowSet);
        } else {
            tableModel = new DataSearchTableModel(cachedRowSet);
            dataSearchResultTable.setModel(tableModel);
            this.setCellRendererForDataSearchTable();
            ((DataSearchTableModel) tableModel).structureChanged();
        }
    }
```

In method structureChanged() I call method fireTableStructureChanged(). This ensures that boolean columns are rendered as check boxes.

Next I try to set width of 0 and 1 columns and make them resizable. It doesn't work:

```
private void setCellRendererForDataSearchTable()
    {
        DataSearchResultTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = new DataSearchResultTableCellRenderer();
        TableColumnModel columnModel = dataSearchResultTable.getColumnModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnModel.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(i);
            if (i == 0) {
                column.setMaxWidth(15);
                column.setResizable(false);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                column.setMaxWidth(30);
                column.setResizable(false);
            }
            column.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
        }
    }
```

My renderer sets only border for selected cells.
My table model is more interesting:

```
public DataSearchTableModel(CachedRowSet cachedRowSet)
    {
        this.cachedRowSet = cachedRowSet;
        updateModel(this.cachedRowSet);
    }

    public void updateModel(CachedRowSet cachedRowSet)
    {
        try {
            metaData = this.cachedRowSet.getMetaData();
            this.numOfCols = metaData.getColumnCount();
            // Retrieve the number of rows.
            this.cachedRowSet.beforeFirst();
            this.numOfRows = 0;
            while (this.cachedRowSet.next()) {
                this.numOfRows++;
            }
            this.cachedRowSet.beforeFirst();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't work, those columns are still resized and with wrong width?

Thanks!

Comment: Change the resize of the table to `JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`.  You may also want to try setting the actual and preferred width of the columns as well

Comment: Yes, this is good option AUTo_RESIZE_OFF but I want to set only first and second columns to specific width depending on their header's width. Only 1 and 2 column width should never change.

Comment: May be you need to use `TableColumn c = new TableColumn();c.setResizable(false);` ?

Comment: works .................

Comment: The issue is probably(rather almost likely) with `firTableStructureChanged()` call

Comment: @Volodymyr Levytskyi as your standard...., no idea without an SSCCE, ColumnModel doen't exist after  fireTableStructureChanged, you need to call and set ColumnModel again, test if fireDataChanged caused with the same issue

Comment: btw (and just for emphasis), your model implementation is incorrect because it doesn't notify its listener in updateCachedRowSet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In method structureChanged() I call method
>   **fireTableStructureChanged()**. This ensures that boolean columns are
>   rendered as check boxes.
>   (and...............)
>   But this doesn't work, those columns are still resized and with wrong
>   width?

with **`JTable.setModel(model)`** call or upon receiving the event fired by **`fireTableStructureChanged`** function call, if `autoCreateColumnsFromModel` is `set(true)` `JTable` will *discards* any table columns that it had prior to these function call and *reallocates default columns* in the order they appear in the model. Which means all the options related to column(width, renderer, etc) you set to the column previously will be lost. Setting `autoCreateColumnsFromModel` flag to `false` should be sufficient. To set or unset this flag use:

```
JTable.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(boolean)
```

Or, you may need to reset all the options to column *after* these function call.

**Reference:**

1. [public void fireTableStructureChanged()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableStructureChanged%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for reply but if I set autoCreateColumnsFromModel to false my jtable doesn't display any rows at all. If I just remove fireTableStructureChanged() then I have my columns of correct width and not resizable but boolean columns are rendered without checkbox as string true.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi, did you try setting the `autoCreateColumnsFromModel` to false,  right after the initialization of your `JTable` ?

Comment: please, post a short working example reproducing your problem and attach it in your answer. I will look into it

Comment: it is easier to give up than posting sscce because TableModel is built by cachedrowset which comes from my db. Thsnks for your help. I'll solve it myself.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi, To be specific, first create your `model` instance,  then create table instance `table = new JTable(model);` and then do `table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);`. Any change on model after this should not be any problem. If still it doesn't work then i don't think i can be much helpful here without code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
public void resizeColumn(JTable tbl, int column) {
  tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setPrefferedSize(new Dimension(/*width*/, /*height*/));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found solution.

You should never call fireTableStructureChanged after you customize your TableColumns.
But to update table after its model and renderer was set you need fireTableStructureChanged.

So at first set cell renderers then call fireTableStructureChanged to make boolean columns displaed with checkboxes and only then change your TableColumns.

It will work.

Comment: I'm would be delete this post by moving to question, because is supra_magnet for down_voters

Comment: I don't know how this answer might be different from the one i have described. But good job for finding your solution. As mKorbel said, your post is not really a good answer, don't get us wrong. Add what you have written in the post to your question with bold title: **Solved:**

Comment: it's wrong to fire events on behalf of the model, always ... -1 as expected :-)

Comment: off-course, kleopatra never forgets to punish people with her down voting privilege ;)

Comment: @Sage no punishment, just saving future readers from going into the wrong direction :-)

Comment: It's not punishment to me, it's punishment to those who do that! But in this case @kleopatra acts fairly, maybe.